# Outlook 2010: When sending message on behalf of someone else, store that message in the other person's Sent Items folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

We have an e-mail account for support purposes which is tended to by multiple members of the team. When answering a support e-mail we obviously choose the support account as sender. Still, the answer is not stored in the support account's Sent Items folder, but in the Sent Items of the person actually answering.

This behavior, which seems to be by design, prevents others from gaining access to the entire conversation and potentially causes multiple answers.

I am looking for an automated way of moving e-mails sent on behalf of someone else to that person's Sent Items folder.

I tried to create a rule for this but could not find the right setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outlook 2010 allows multiple Exchange mailbox connections.  Just add the support mailbox as an additional account.  To do this you must go through the control panel 'Mail' (Mail (32bit) on a x64 machine) option.  Select the 'Email Accounts' button and add the mailbox.

I assume your current configuration is by adding the support mailbox as an additional mailbox to your primary account, which as you've found has its limitations.

Comment: Nice and simple solution ;-) Thank you!